# Isomorphism of square zero extension algebras related to Hochschild cohomology

Tags: abstract-algebra, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, hochschild-cohomology

I'm trying to solve exercise 5.14 of [these notes](http://www.ltcc.ac.uk/media/london-taught-course-centre/documents/HomAlg2020-final.pdf).

Let $A$ be an algebra over a commutative ring $k$ and $M$ an $A$-$A$-bimodule. Define on the direct sum module $A\oplus M$ the square zero extension algebra given by the product
$$
  (a, m) (b, n) = (ab, an + mb + \alpha(a, b))
$$
where $\alpha \colon A \times A \to M$ is a bilinear map and considered the induced map $\alpha \colon A \otimes_k A \to M$. For this product to be associative, it is easily verified that
$$
  aα(b ⊗ c) − α(ab⊗  c) + α(a⊗  bc) − α(a⊗  b)c = 0 \,,
$$
which is precisely the condition $\alpha \in \ker(\delta^2)$, where $\delta^2 \colon \hom(A^{\otimes 2}, M) \to \hom(A^{\otimes 3}, M)$ is the Hochschild coboundary operator. Denote this associative algebra by $T_\alpha(A \oplus M)$. The exercise asks the following.

> Let $α, α' ∈ \ker(δ^2)$. Show that there is an isomorphism
> of algebras $T_α(A ⊕ M) \cong T_{α'}(A ⊕ M)$ which induces the identity on the ideal $M$ and on the quotient $A$ if and only if $α$ and $α'$ determine the same class in $\mathrm{HH}^2(A; M)$ (the Hochschild cohomology of $A$ with coefficients in $M$).

First of all, I’m very confused by the fact that the isomorphism induces the identity on $A$ and $M$, because that means that it is the identity on $A \oplus M$ so we would have $\alpha = \alpha'$.

On the other hand, if I forget about that and consider an algebra homomorphism $F$, after imposing that products map to products what I get is
$$
  F(ab) = F(a) F(b)
$$
for all $a, b ∈ A$, and
$$
  F(an) + F(mb) + F\alpha(a,b)
  = F(a) F(n) + F(m) F(b) + \alpha'(F(a), F(b))
$$

Now I don’t know how to use the fact that $F$ is an isomorphism.

Considering the converse implication, the fact that $α$ and $α'$ determine the same class in $\mathrm{HH}^2(A; M)$ means that $\alpha - \alpha' = \delta^1(G)$ for some $G \colon A \to M$, but I don’t really know how to use this fact to define a homomorphism.

**EDIT.**
The equalities above come from a mistake, so they’re not true in general.

Imposing the homomorphism condition we have
$$
  F((a, m) (a, n))
  = F(ab, an + mb + \alpha(a,b))
  = F(a, m) F(b, n)
  = (a, m') (b, n') \,.
$$
The last equality comes from the fact that $F$ induces the identity on the quotient $A$. If $a = 0$ or $b = 0$ then, using that $F$ is the identity on $M$ I get
$$
  an + mb + \alpha(a, b) = an' + m'b + \alpha'(a, b) \,.
$$
Thus
$$
  \alpha(a, b) - \alpha'(a, b) = a(n' - n) + (m' - m)b \,.
$$

**EDIT.**
For the converse I’ve thought of defining the map $(a, m) \mapsto (a, m + G(a))$. The fact that this is an algebra homomorphism is equivalent to $\alpha(a, b) - \alpha'(a, b) = a G(b) - G(ab) + G(a) b$. This map is an isomorphism and induces the required identities. Therefore I think I have this implication.

Comment: You corrupted the statement "induces the identity on the ideal $M$ and on the quotient $A$" to "induces the identity on $A$ and $M$". The words "ideal" and "quotient" were important. To induce the identity on the **ideal** $M$ means what you think it means (i.e., applying the map to an $m \in M$ gives $m$ again). But to induce the identity on the **quotient** $A$ means that applying the map to an element $\left(a,m\right) \in A \oplus M$ gives a pair whose first entry is $a$.

Comment: You don't need to use the fact that $F$ is an isomorphism; it suffices that it is a homomorphism. Indeed, a linear map from $A \oplus M$ to $A \oplus M$ that induces the identity on the ideal $M$ and on the quotient $A$ must automatically be invertible, as you can check (exercise!).

Comment: @darijgrinberg For the isomorphism, as vector spaces I can show it using coordinates. For instance assuming $A$ and $M$ have dimension 1 to simplify it, the map $F$ would be defined by $F(1,0)=(1,m)$ and $F(0,1)=(0,1)$. And this map is clearly an isomorphism. But I don't know how to prove it without using coordinates, which is only valid for finite dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: And still I would have to show that the inverse of the linear map extends to the algebra as the inverse of the extension of the linear map. I guess there's where $\alpha$'s will appear.

Comment: I've added some more of my try, would you mind writing an answer including the fact that linear implies isomorphism? @darijgrinberg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isomorphisms $\psi$ which are the identity on $M$ are determined by $A\to A\oplus M$, and inducing identity on the quotient means identified with a map $\phi: A\to M$.

so compute that its an algebra isomorphism two ways:

$$\psi(a\oplus 0 \cdot_1 b\oplus 0) = \psi(ab\oplus \delta_1(a,b)) = ab\oplus (\phi(ab) +\delta_1(a,b))$$

$$\psi(a\oplus0)\cdot_2\psi(b\oplus0) = (a\oplus \phi(a))\cdot_2(b\oplus \phi(b)) = ab\oplus (a\phi(b) + \phi(a)b+ \delta_2(a,b))$$

Equating the two, $\phi$ is coboundary between $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$